# convert timestamp column to milliseconds in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I want to convert the timestamp column in Oracle DB to milliseconds.

The timestamp column values are converted to Canada/Mountain timezone and added as Timestamp value and since it is already in Canada/Mountain timezone, i just want to convert it to milliseconds through sql.

The issue is that when i run my query locally it runs fine and gives output properly. But when the same is deployed on the server the value differs

for example :

Timestamp value in DB : 2020-10-22 09:46:27.000000000 AM

Converted milliseconds in local : 1666239387000 which when converted back is **Thursday, October 20, 2022 9:46:27 AM** which is correct

Converted milliseconds on server : 1666280787000 which when converted back is **Thursday, October 20, 2022 9:16:27 PM** which is wrong

I want the milliseconds to be same as local milliseconds value.

Any guidance would be helpful

I'm making use of below query

```
SELECT 
(EXTRACT(DAY FROM create_interval) * 24 * 60 * 60 + EXTRACT(HOUR FROM create_interval) * 60 * 60 + EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM create_interval) * 60 + EXTRACT(SECOND FROM create_interval)) * 1000 AS createdDate
 FROM 
( SELECT (FROM_TZ(CREATEDDATE, 'Canada/Mountain') - TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC') AS create_interval 
FROM table_name WHERE IDENTIFICATIONKEY = 'id')
```

Here is the SS of the CREATEDDATE column type

[CREATED DATE COLUMN TYPE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrcuC.png)

Comment: What is the data type of column `CREATEDDATE`? And how do you convert back?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit its TIMESTAMP(6)

Comment: Are you sure? Not `TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE` or `TIMESTAMP(6) WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE`? It should be the same output. Is it really the same value?

Comment: Yes I'm sure. I've attached the SS in the post for reference

Comment: According online Unix epoch converter `2020-10-22 09:46:27 Canada/Mountain` (which is `22.10.2020 15:46:27 UTC`) result should be 1603381587000 as in mine or MT0 answer - not 1666239387000 nor 1666280787000. Verify your input values.

Comment: Does localTImzone also affect the query?? or even session timezone??

Comment: No, it does not

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit we are using mybatis framework for custom sql. WIll the be causing the issue??

Comment: For this we would need to know the generated command

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit i've commented on your answer on the generated sql in mybatis. Hope that is what you were asking else please let me know what generated command is.

Comment: Also one more i might have forgotten to tell is that the DBTImeZone is UTC (+00:00) but the values stored in the timestamp column is in MDT converted value

Comment: What is MDT? Please use only the IANA timezone names.I guess it is a problem with your input data. On September 24, 2020, Yukon switched the time zone (no DST) and as you see already in my answer there a quite a lot of recent changes for "time in canada"

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit yes, I have changed it to America/Denver on your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Try this on server and local, it should return the same value.

```
WITH t AS (
   SELECT 
      FROM_TZ(TIMESTAMP '2020-10-22 09:46:27', 'Canada/Mountain') - 
      TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' AS create_interval 
   FROM dual)
SELECT (
   EXTRACT(DAY FROM create_interval) * 24 * 60 * 60 + 
   EXTRACT(HOUR FROM create_interval) * 60 * 60 +
   EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM create_interval) * 60 +
   EXTRACT(SECOND FROM create_interval) ) * 1000 AS createdDate
FROM t
```

Or use time zone `America/Edmonton` which seems to be the official name, whereas `Canada/Mountain` is just an alias.

Also execute `SELECT * FROM v$timezone_file;` - is there any difference?

If the time would differ only by one hour, then it could be a problem with the time zone file, DST rule for `America/Edmonton` was changed in 1987.

Based on [IANA database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) DST rules are rather "dynamic" I would say:

```
# Zone  NAME        STDOFF  RULES   FORMAT  [UNTIL]
Zone America/Edmonton   -7:33:52 -  LMT 1906 Sep
            -7:00   Edm M%sT    1987
            -7:00   Canada  M%sT


# British Columbia

# From Paul Eggert (2006-03-22):
# Shanks & Pottenger write that since 1970 most of this region has
# been like Vancouver.
# Dawson Creek uses MST.  Much of east BC is like Edmonton.

# From Matt Johnson (2015-09-21):
# Fort Nelson, BC, Canada will cancel DST this year.  So while previously they
# were aligned with America/Vancouver, they're now aligned with
# America/Dawson_Creek.
# http://www.northernrockies.ca/EN/meta/news/archives/2015/northern-rockies-time-change.html
#
# From Tim Parenti (2015-09-23):
# This requires a new zone for the Northern Rockies Regional Municipality,
# America/Fort_Nelson.  The resolution of 2014-12-08 was reached following a
# 2014-11-15 poll with nearly 75% support.  Effectively, the municipality has
# been on MST (-0700) like Dawson Creek since it advanced its clocks on
# 2015-03-08.
#
# From Paul Eggert (2019-07-25):
# Shanks says Fort Nelson did not observe DST in 1946, unlike Vancouver.
# Alois Treindl confirmed this on 07-22, citing the 1946-04-27 Vancouver Daily
# Province.  He also cited the 1946-09-28 Victoria Daily Times, which said
# that Vancouver, Victoria, etc. "change at midnight Saturday"; for now,
# guess they meant 02:00 Sunday since 02:00 was common practice in Vancouver.
#
# Early Vancouver, Volume Four, by Major J.S. Matthews, V.D., 2011 edition
# says that a 1922 plebiscite adopted DST, but a 1923 plebiscite rejected it.
# http://former.vancouver.ca/ctyclerk/archives/digitized/EarlyVan/SearchEarlyVan/Vol4pdf/MatthewsEarlyVancouverVol4_DaylightSavings.pdf
# A catalog entry for a newspaper clipping seems to indicate that Vancouver
# observed DST in 1941 from 07-07 through 09-27; see
# https://searcharchives.vancouver.ca/daylight-saving-1918-starts-again-july-7-1941-start-d-s-sept-27-end-of-d-s-1941
# We have no further details, so omit them for now.

# Rule  NAME    FROM    TO  -   IN  ON  AT  SAVE    LETTER/S
Rule    Vanc    1918    only    -   Apr 14  2:00    1:00    D
Rule    Vanc    1918    only    -   Oct 27  2:00    0   S
Rule    Vanc    1942    only    -   Feb  9  2:00    1:00    W # War
Rule    Vanc    1945    only    -   Aug 14  23:00u  1:00    P # Peace
Rule    Vanc    1945    only    -   Sep 30  2:00    0   S
Rule    Vanc    1946    1986    -   Apr lastSun 2:00    1:00    D
Rule    Vanc    1946    only    -   Sep 29  2:00    0   S
Rule    Vanc    1947    1961    -   Sep lastSun 2:00    0   S
Rule    Vanc    1962    2006    -   Oct lastSun 2:00    0   S
# Zone  NAME        STDOFF  RULES   FORMAT  [UNTIL]
Zone America/Vancouver  -8:12:28 -  LMT 1884
            -8:00   Vanc    P%sT    1987
            -8:00   Canada  P%sT
Zone America/Dawson_Creek -8:00:56 -    LMT 1884
            -8:00   Canada  P%sT    1947
            -8:00   Vanc    P%sT    1972 Aug 30  2:00
            -7:00   -   MST
Zone America/Fort_Nelson    -8:10:47 -  LMT 1884
            -8:00   Vanc    P%sT    1946
            -8:00   -   PST 1947
            -8:00   Vanc    P%sT    1987
            -8:00   Canada  P%sT    2015 Mar  8  2:00
            -7:00   -   MST
# For Creston see America/Phoenix.

# Northwest Territories, Nunavut, Yukon

# From Chris Walton (2022-11-06):
# Whitehorse Star - Thursday April 22, 1965 - page 1
# title: DST Starts Monday ...
# https://www.newspapers.com/image/578587481/
# The title of this first article is wrong and/or misleading.
# Also, the start time shown in the  article is vague; it simply says "after
# midnight" when it probably should have stated 2:00a.m....
#
# Whitehorse Star - Monday October 25, 1965 - page 15 ...
# https://www.newspapers.com/image/578589147/
# The 1965 Yukon Council minutes can be found here:
# http://assets.yukonarchives.ca/PER_YG_06_1965_C20_S02_v1.pdf
# ... I do not currently believe that NWT touched any of its clocks in 1965....
#
# Whitehorse Star - Thursday Feb 24,1966 - page 2
# title: It's Time for YDT ...
# https://www.newspapers.com/image/578575979/ ...
# America/Whitehorse as a permanent change from UTC-9(YST) to
# UTC-8(PST) at 00:00 on Sunday February 27, 1966....
#
# Whitehorse Star - Friday April 28,1972 - page 6
# title: Daylight Saving Time for N.W.T....
# https://www.newspapers.com/image/578701610/ ...
# Nunavut and NWT zones ... DST starting in 1972.... Start and End ...
# should be the same as the rest of Canada
#
#
# From Paul Eggert (2022-11-06):
# For now, assume Yukon's 1965-04-22 spring forward was 00:00 -> 02:00, as this
# seems likely than 02:00 -> 04:00 and matches "after midnight".

# From Paul Eggert (2006-03-22):
# Dawson switched to PST in 1973.  Inuvik switched to MST in 1979.
# Mathew Englander (1996-10-07) gives the following refs:
#   * 1967. Paragraph 28(34)(g) of the Interpretation Act, S.C. 1967-68,
#   c. 7 defines Yukon standard time as UTC-9....
#   see Interpretation Act, R.S.C. 1985, c. I-21, s. 35(1).
#   [https://www.canlii.org/en/ca/laws/stat/rsc-1985-c-i-21/latest/rsc-1985-c-i-21.html]
#   * C.O. 1973/214 switched Yukon to PST on 1973-10-28 00:00.
#   * O.I.C. 1980/02 established DST.
#   * O.I.C. 1987/056 changed DST to Apr firstSun 2:00 to Oct lastSun 2:00.

# From Brian Inglis (2015-04-14):
#
# I tried to trace the history of Yukon time and found the following
# regulations, giving the reference title and URL if found, regulation name,
# and relevant quote if available.  Each regulation specifically revokes its
# predecessor.  The final reference is to the current Interpretation Act
# authorizing and resulting from these regulatory changes.
#
# Only recent regulations were retrievable via Yukon government site search or
# index, and only some via Canadian legal sources.  Other sources used include
# articles titled "Standard Time and Time Zones in Canada" from JRASC via ADS
# Abstracts, cited by ADO for 1932 ..., and updated versions from 1958 and
# 1970 quoted below; each article includes current extracts from provincial
# and territorial ST and DST regulations at the end, summaries and details of
# standard times and daylight saving time at many locations across Canada,
# with time zone maps, tables and calculations for Canadian Sunrise, Sunset,
# and LMST; they also cover many countries and global locations, with a chart
# and table showing current Universal Time offsets, and may be useful as
# another source of information for 1970 and earlier.
#
# * Standard Time and Time Zones in Canada; Smith, C.C.; JRASC, Vol. 26,
#   pp.49-77; February 1932; SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System (ADS)
#   http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1932JRASC..26...49S from p.75:
#   Yukon Interpretation Ordinance
#   Yukon standard time is the local mean time at the one hundred and
#   thirty-fifth meridian.
#
# * Standard Time and Time Zones in Canada; Smith, C.C.; Thomson, Malcolm M.;
#   JRASC, Vol. 52, pp.193-223; October 1958; SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System
#   (ADS) http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1958JRASC..52..193S from pp.220-1:
#   Yukon Interpretation Ordinance, 1955, Chap. 16.
#
#     (1) Subject to this section, standard time shall be reckoned as nine
#     hours behind Greenwich Time and called Yukon Standard Time.
#
#     (2) Notwithstanding subsection (1), the Commissioner may make regulations
#     varying the manner of reckoning standard time.
#
# * Yukon Territory Commissioner's Order 1966-20 Interpretation Ordinance
#   [no online source found]
#
# * Standard Time and Time Zones in Canada; Thomson, Malcolm M.; JRASC,
#   Vol. 64, pp.129-162; June 1970; SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System (ADS)
#   http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1970JRASC..64..129T from p.156: Yukon
#   Territory Commissioner's Order 1967-59 Interpretation Ordinance ...
#
#     1. Commissioner's Order 1966-20 dated at Whitehorse in the Yukon
#     Territory on 27th January, 1966, is hereby revoked.
#
#     2. Yukon (East) Standard Time as defined by section 36 of the
#     Interpretation Ordinance from and after mid-night on the 28th day of May,
#     1967 shall be reckoned in the same manner as Pacific Standard Time, that
#     is to say, eight hours behind Greenwich Time in the area of the Yukon
#     Territory lying east of the 138th degree longitude west.
#
#     3. In the remainder of the Territory, lying west of the 138th degree
#     longitude west, Yukon (West) Standard Time shall be reckoned as nine
#     hours behind Greenwich Time.
#
# * Yukon Standard Time defined as Pacific Standard Time, YCO 1973/214
#   https://www.canlii.org/en/yk/laws/regu/yco-1973-214/latest/yco-1973-214.html
#   C.O. 1973/214 INTERPRETATION ACT ...
#
#     1. Effective October 28, 1973 Commissioner's Order 1967/59 is hereby
#     revoked.
#
#     2. Yukon Standard Time as defined by section 36 of the Interpretation
#     Act from and after midnight on the twenty-eighth day of October, 1973
#     shall be reckoned in the same manner as Pacific Standard Time, that is
#     to say eight hours behind Greenwich Time.
#
# * O.I.C. 1980/02 INTERPRETATION ACT
#   https://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz/attachments/20201125/d5adc93b/CAYTOIC1980-02DST1980-01-04-0001.pdf
#
# * Yukon Daylight Saving Time, YOIC 1987/56
#   https://www.canlii.org/en/yk/laws/regu/yoic-1987-56/latest/yoic-1987-56.html
#   O.I.C. 1987/056 INTERPRETATION ACT ...
#
#   In every year between
#     (a) two o'clock in the morning in the first Sunday in April, and
#     (b) two o'clock in the morning in the last Sunday in October,
#   Standard Time shall be reckoned as seven hours behind Greenwich Time and
#   called Yukon Daylight Saving Time.
#   ...
#   Dated ... 9th day of March, A.D., 1987.
#
# * Yukon Daylight Saving Time 2006, YOIC 2006/127
#   https://www.canlii.org/en/yk/laws/regu/yoic-2006-127/latest/yoic-2006-127.html
#   O.I.C. 2006/127 INTERPRETATION ACT ...
#
#     1. In Yukon each year the time for general purposes shall be 7 hours
#     behind Greenwich mean time during the period commencing at two o'clock
#     in the forenoon on the second Sunday of March and ending at two o'clock
#     in the forenoon on the first Sunday of November and shall be called
#     Yukon Daylight Saving Time.
#
#     2. Order-in-Council 1987/56 is revoked.
#
#     3. This order comes into force January 1, 2007.
#
# * Interpretation Act, RSY 2002, c 125
# https://www.canlii.org/en/yk/laws/stat/rsy-2002-c-125/latest/rsy-2002-c-125.html

# From Chris Walton (2022-11-06):
# The 5th edition of the Atlas of Canada contains a time zone map that
# shows both legislated and observed time zone boundaries.
# All communities on Baffin Island are shown to be observing Eastern time.
# The date on the map is 1984.
# https://ftp.maps.canada.ca/pub/nrcan_rncan/raster/atlas_5_ed/eng/other/referencemaps/mcr4056.pdf

# From Rives McDow (1999-09-04):
# Nunavut ... moved ... to incorporate the whole territory into one time zone.
# Nunavut moves to single time zone Oct. 31
# http://www.nunatsiaq.com/nunavut/nvt90903_13.html

# From Paul Eggert (1999-09-20):
# Basic Facts: The New Territory
# http://www.nunavut.com/basicfacts/english/basicfacts_1territory.html
# (1999) reports that ... Coral Harbour does not observe DST.

# From Paul Eggert (2000-10-02):
# Matthews and Vincent (1998) say the following, but we lack histories
# for these potential new Zones.
#
# The Canadian Forces station at Alert uses Eastern Time while the
# handful of residents at the Eureka weather station [in the Central
# zone] skip daylight savings.  Baffin Island, which is crossed by the
# Central, Eastern and Atlantic Time zones only uses Eastern Time.
# Gjoa Haven, Taloyoak and Pelly Bay all use Mountain instead of
# Central Time and Southampton Island [in the Central zone] is not
# required to use daylight savings.

# From <http://www.nunatsiaqonline.ca/archives/nunavut001130/nvt21110_02.html>
# Nunavut now has two time zones (2000-11-10):
# The Nunavut government would allow its employees in Kugluktuk and
# Cambridge Bay to operate on central time year-round, putting them
# one hour behind the rest of Nunavut for six months during the winter.
# At the end of October the two communities had rebelled against
# Nunavut's unified time zone, refusing to shift to eastern time with
# the rest of the territory for the winter.  Cambridge Bay remained on
# central time, while Kugluktuk, even farther west, reverted to
# mountain time, which they had used before the advent of Nunavut's
# unified time zone in 1999.
#
# From Rives McDow (2001-01-20), quoting the Nunavut government:
# The preceding decision came into effect at midnight, Saturday Nov 4, 2000.

# From Paul Eggert (2000-12-04):
# Let's just keep track of the official times for now.

# From Rives McDow (2001-03-07):
# The premier of Nunavut has issued a ministerial statement advising
# that effective 2001-04-01, the territory of Nunavut will revert
# back to three time zones (mountain, central, and eastern).  Of the
# cities in Nunavut, Coral Harbor is the only one that I know of that
# has said it will not observe dst, staying on EST year round.  I'm
# checking for more info, and will get back to you if I come up with
# more.
# [Also see <http://www.nunatsiaq.com/nunavut/nvt10309_06.html> (2001-03-09).]

# From Gwillim Law (2005-05-21):
# According to ...
# http://www.canadiangeographic.ca/Magazine/SO98/geomap.asp
# (from a 1998 Canadian Geographic article), the de facto and de jure time
# for Southampton Island (at the north end of Hudson Bay) is UTC-5 all year
# round.  Using Google, it's easy to find other websites that confirm this.
# I wasn't able to find how far back this time regimen goes, but since it
# predates the creation of Nunavut, it probably goes back many years....
# The Inuktitut name of Coral Harbour is Sallit, but it's rarely used.
#
# From Paul Eggert (2014-10-17):
# For lack of better information, assume that Southampton Island observed
# daylight saving only during wartime.  Gwillim Law's email also
# mentioned maps now maintained by National Research Council Canada;
# see above for an up-to-date link.

# From Chris Walton (2007-03-01):
# ... the community of Resolute (located on Cornwallis Island in
# Nunavut) moved from Central Time to Eastern Time last November.
# Basically the community did not change its clocks at the end of
# daylight saving....
# http://www.nnsl.com/frames/newspapers/2006-11/nov13_06none.html

# From Chris Walton (2011-03-21):
# Back in 2007 I initiated the creation of a new "zone file" for Resolute
# Bay. Resolute Bay is a small community located about 900km north of
# the Arctic Circle. The zone file was required because Resolute Bay had
# decided to use UTC-5 instead of UTC-6 for the winter of 2006-2007.
#
# According to new information which I received last week, Resolute Bay
# went back to using UTC-6 in the winter of 2007-2008...
#
# On March 11/2007 most of Canada went onto daylight saving. On March
# 14/2007 I phoned the Resolute Bay hamlet office to do a "time check." I
# talked to somebody that was both knowledgeable and helpful. I was able
# to confirm that Resolute Bay was still operating on UTC-5. It was
# explained to me that Resolute Bay had been on the Eastern Time zone
# (EST) in the winter, and was now back on the Central Time zone (CDT).
# i.e. the time zone had changed twice in the last year but the clocks
# had not moved. The residents had to know which time zone they were in
# so they could follow the correct TV schedule...
#
# On Nov 02/2008 most of Canada went onto standard time. On Nov 03/2008 I
# phoned the Resolute Bay hamlet office...[D]ue to the challenging nature
# of the phone call, I decided to seek out an alternate source of
# information. I found an e-mail address for somebody by the name of
# Stephanie Adams whose job was listed as "Inns North Support Officer for
# Arctic Co-operatives." I was under the impression that Stephanie lived
# and worked in Resolute Bay...
#
# On March 14/2011 I phoned the hamlet office again. I was told that
# Resolute Bay had been using Central Standard Time over the winter of
# 2010-2011 and that the clocks had therefore been moved one hour ahead
# on March 13/2011. The person I talked to was aware that Resolute Bay
# had previously experimented with Eastern Standard Time but he could not
# tell me when the practice had stopped.
#
# On March 17/2011 I searched the Web to find an e-mail address of
# somebody that might be able to tell me exactly when Resolute Bay went
# off Eastern Standard Time. I stumbled on the name "Aziz Kheraj." Aziz
# used to be the mayor of Resolute Bay and he apparently owns half the
# businesses including "South Camp Inn." This website has some info on
# Aziz:
# http://www.uphere.ca/node/493
#
# I sent Aziz an e-mail asking when Resolute Bay had stopped using
# Eastern Standard Time.
#
# Aziz responded quickly with this: "hi, The time was not changed for the
# 1 year only, the following year, the community went back to the old way
# of "spring ahead-fall behind" currently we are zulu plus 5 hrs and in
# the winter Zulu plus 6 hrs"
#
# This of course conflicted with everything I had ascertained in November 2008.
#
# I sent Aziz a copy of my 2008 e-mail exchange with Stephanie. Aziz
# responded with this: "Hi, Stephanie lives in Winnipeg. I live here, You
# may want to check with the weather office in Resolute Bay or do a
# search on the weather through Env. Canada. web site"
#
# If I had realized the Stephanie did not live in Resolute Bay I would
# never have contacted her.  I now believe that all the information I
# obtained in November 2008 should be ignored...
# I apologize for reporting incorrect information in 2008.

# From Tim Parenti (2020-03-05):
# The government of Yukon announced [yesterday] the cessation of seasonal time
# changes.  "After clocks are pushed ahead one hour on March 8, the territory
# will remain on [UTC-07].  ... [The government] found 93 per cent of
# respondents wanted to end seasonal time changes and, of that group, 70 per
# cent wanted 'permanent Pacific Daylight Saving Time.'"
# https://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/north/yukon-end-daylight-saving-time-1.5486358
#
# Although the government press release prefers PDT, we prefer MST for
# consistency with nearby Dawson Creek, Creston, and Fort Nelson.
# https://yukon.ca/en/news/yukon-end-seasonal-time-change

# From Andrew G. Smith (2020-09-24):
# Yukon has completed its regulatory change to be on UTC -7 year-round....
# http://www.gov.yk.ca/legislation/regs/oic2020_125.pdf
# What we have done is re-defined Yukon Standard Time, as we are
# authorized to do under section 33 of our Interpretation Act:
# http://www.gov.yk.ca/legislation/acts/interpretation_c.pdf
#
# From Paul Eggert (2020-09-24):
# tzdb uses the obsolete YST abbreviation for standard time in Yukon through
# about 1970, and uses PST for standard time in Yukon since then.  Consistent
# with that, use MST for -07, the new standard time in Yukon effective Nov. 1.

# Rule  NAME    FROM    TO  -   IN  ON  AT  SAVE    LETTER/S
Rule    NT_YK   1918    only    -   Apr 14  2:00    1:00    D
Rule    NT_YK   1918    only    -   Oct 27  2:00    0   S
Rule    NT_YK   1919    only    -   May 25  2:00    1:00    D
Rule    NT_YK   1919    only    -   Nov  1  0:00    0   S
Rule    NT_YK   1942    only    -   Feb  9  2:00    1:00    W # War
Rule    NT_YK   1945    only    -   Aug 14  23:00u  1:00    P # Peace
Rule    NT_YK   1945    only    -   Sep 30  2:00    0   S
Rule    NT_YK   1972    1986    -   Apr lastSun 2:00    1:00    D
Rule    NT_YK   1972    2006    -   Oct lastSun 2:00    0   S
Rule    NT_YK   1987    2006    -   Apr Sun>=1  2:00    1:00    D
Rule    Yukon   1965    only    -   Apr lastSun 0:00    2:00    DD
Rule    Yukon   1965    only    -   Oct lastSun 2:00    0   S
# Zone  NAME        STDOFF  RULES   FORMAT  [UNTIL]
# formerly Frobisher Bay
Zone America/Iqaluit    0   -   -00 1942 Aug # Frobisher Bay est.
            -5:00   NT_YK   E%sT    1999 Oct 31  2:00
            -6:00   Canada  C%sT    2000 Oct 29  2:00
            -5:00   Canada  E%sT
# aka Qausuittuq
Zone America/Resolute   0   -   -00 1947 Aug 31 # Resolute founded
            -6:00   NT_YK   C%sT    2000 Oct 29  2:00
            -5:00   -   EST 2001 Apr  1  3:00
            -6:00   Canada  C%sT    2006 Oct 29  2:00
            -5:00   -   EST 2007 Mar 11  3:00
            -6:00   Canada  C%sT
# aka Kangiqiniq
Zone America/Rankin_Inlet 0 -   -00 1957 # Rankin Inlet founded
            -6:00   NT_YK   C%sT    2000 Oct 29  2:00
            -5:00   -   EST 2001 Apr  1  3:00
            -6:00   Canada  C%sT
# aka Iqaluktuuttiaq
Zone America/Cambridge_Bay 0    -   -00 1920 # trading post est.?
            -7:00   NT_YK   M%sT    1999 Oct 31  2:00
            -6:00   Canada  C%sT    2000 Oct 29  2:00
            -5:00   -   EST 2000 Nov  5  0:00
            -6:00   -   CST 2001 Apr  1  3:00
            -7:00   Canada  M%sT
Zone America/Inuvik 0   -   -00 1953 # Inuvik founded
            -8:00   NT_YK   P%sT    1979 Apr lastSun  2:00
            -7:00   NT_YK   M%sT    1980
            -7:00   Canada  M%sT
Zone America/Whitehorse -9:00:12 -  LMT 1900 Aug 20
            -9:00   NT_YK   Y%sT    1965
            -9:00   Yukon   Y%sT    1966 Feb 27  0:00
            -8:00   -   PST 1980
            -8:00   Canada  P%sT    2020 Nov  1
            -7:00   -   MST
Zone America/Dawson -9:17:40 -  LMT 1900 Aug 20
            -9:00   NT_YK   Y%sT    1965
            -9:00   Yukon   Y%sT    1973 Oct 28  0:00
            -8:00   -   PST 1980
            -8:00   Canada  P%sT    2020 Nov  1
            -7:00   -   MST
```

Comment: I'll try this and let you know. Also should i replace both dual and t to my table_name??

Comment: Try both, I just like to ensure that input value is really the same.

Comment: It runs fine locally and i got the same output i.e. 1603381587000. But when run on server i get the value as 1666280787000 (Thursday, October 20, 2022 9:16:27 PM) which is wrong. 

same as @MT0's result

Comment: WITH t AS (
   SELECT 
      FROM_TZ(createddate, 'America/Edmonton') - 
      TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' AS create_interval 
   FROM table_name
    WHERE IDENTIFICATIONKEY = 'key')
SELECT (
   EXTRACT(DAY FROM create_interval) * 24 * 60 * 60 + 
   EXTRACT(HOUR FROM create_interval) * 60 * 60 +
   EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM create_interval) * 60 +
   EXTRACT(SECOND FROM create_interval) ) * 1000 AS createdDate
FROM t

This is the generated SQL before it gets executed. I've replaced identificationKey and tableName values.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the `TIMESTAMP(6)` to a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` using `FROM_TZ(createddate, 'Canada/Mountain')` to put it in the correct time zone and then use `AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'` to find the equivalent UTC time.

Once you have done that then you can either use `EXTRACT` or subtract dates to find the epoch time since `1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`:

```sql
SELECT ROUND(
         (TRUNC(ts, 'MI') - DATE '1970-01-01') * 86400000
         + EXTRACT(SECOND FROM ts) * 1000
       ) AS epoch_time_ms
FROM   (
  SELECT FROM_TZ(createddate, 'Canada/Mountain') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS ts
  FROM   table_name
);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  identificationkey VARCHAR2(10),
  createddate       TIMESTAMP(6)
);

INSERT INTO table_name (identificationkey, createddate)
VALUES ('id', TIMESTAMP '2020-10-22 09:46:27.000000');
```

Outputs:

| EPOCH_TIME_MS |
| --- |
| 1603381587000 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/YFjNswX4)

Comment: Apart from the fact that you return microseconds rather than milliseconds you can also use `(cast(ts as date) - DATE '1970-01-01') * 86400000`. Be aware that this solution truncates milliseconds from input timestamp value.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Fixed µs to ms. As for your additional comment, I did not use `CAST` explicitly because of the issue of losing the fractional seconds. `TRUNC`ating to the minute and then getting the seconds from the timestamp does not loose the fractional seconds so does not have that issue.

Comment: @MT0 It runs fine locally and i got the same output i.e. 1603381587000. But when run on server i get the value as 1666280787000 (Thursday, October 20, 2022 9:16:27 PM) which is wrong